# EXE from C++, Sqlite dll if any

Tags: c++, sqlite, visual-c++, windows-installer

I am a Java programmer and have come across a very nasty situation. For POC purposes, I need to write down a small segment of my solution that will run as a standalone application doing something very specific.
I have 2 questions:-

1. I can write the code, but what I don't know is how do I create an installer and exe out of that C++ code.
2. Secondly, I need to parse a sqlite db file and show its data in the application. Is there a sqlite windows dll or some C++ library or something that I can use, instead of asking the user to install sqlite (or doing it myself through the installer)? So basically, I don't want an extra program to be pushed in, just a dll or some C++ library..

Please let me know if you have an answer to either or both the issues that I'm facing.

Thanks

Comment: What are "POC purposes"?

Comment: Why the downvotes ? The asker is on the right way, s/he needs a little guidance.

Answer (score 4):

1. Compiling your code will turn it in to an executable.  For distribution, you'll want to build it in Release mode.  I'm not sure what version of Visual Studio you are using, but you might have a "Setup and Deployment" Project type which will enable you to create an installer.  Failing that, you may have to look at InstallShield or a tool like that to ensure that the installer has all necessary files (such as the runtime libraries).
2. SQLLite is called light for a reason!  The source code for it can be incorporated directly in to your project and compiled alongside the rest of the files (see: http://www.sqlite.org/selfcontained.html ).  This means no external libraries are necessary to link against, and no extra DLLs need to be redistributed alongside your executable.